# Appearance of divisor sum in a certain series

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

Let us consider the following equivalence between two series, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I want to show that this equivalence indeed holds.

$$\sum_{n,d=1}^{\infty} d^{k-1}e^{2\pi i d n z} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{d|n} d^{k-1} e^{2\pi i n z}$$
where $d|n$ is defined as $d$ being the divisors of $n$, i.e. $d$ divides $n$. (e.g. $d|10|$ means $d=1,2,5,10$.)

I think I am missing a clue here, can someone shed light on how to see this equivalence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let change the order of sums:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{d|n} d^{k-1} e^{2\pi i n z} = \sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=rd} d^{k-1}e^{2\pi i n z} = \sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \sum_{r=1}^{\infty} d^{k-1}e^{2\pi i r d z} = \sum_{d,r=1}^{\infty} d^{k-1}e^{2\pi i r d z}$$
And just replace $r$ with $n$.

Comment: Regarding the first equality, the sum $n, d|n$ gives several $d$ with the same value, e.g. 2. ($n=2,4,6 \cdots)$ all have divisor $d|n$ 2, so $d$ will be summed over 2 more than once. However, on the right side of the first equality, $d$ is only summed over once. How to think about this?

Comment: @Nugi, For any $d$ we have a sum over $r$, so it counts as many as $r$ we have.